# Show child pages and sibling pages on the child page

Tags: pages

I have a page set up like

Page One
    - Page Red
    - Page Green
    - Page Blue

On Page One I can show the child pages with

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID); 
        ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I show the sibling pages on Page Red, Green and Blue

So on Page Red, Green and Blue I would see Page Red, Page Green, Page Blue

Answer (score 2):

You can query pages that have same parent excluding the page itself:

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&exclude='.$post->ID);
```

Use `parent` instead of `child_of` to get only direct siblings without children of the siblings.

Comment: Hi gmazzap - Thanks for your reply, your code shows all pages

Comment: @user668499 yep, I typed too quickly.  I fixed the code, now should work.